# Any way to implement OAuth integration to an external application with NetSuite?

Tags: oauth, integration, netsuite

I'm trying to implement NetSuite with an external application. My application is embeded to run in an iframe, so I'm using a portlet to load it up and simply display it. Now, the issue is that my app uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication and I would like the users to be able to login using this. NetSuite doesn't seem to provide any kind of support or straightforward way to do this, so I tried to elaborate something on my own.

The idea I had was to configure the app to redirect to a NetSuite restlet to exchange auth_code for tokens and finally get and save the token, but I couldn't make it work for several reasons.

First, RESTlets calls coming from external applications need to have all the authentication headers required by NetSuite.

Second, even if I was able to pull that off, how am I supposed to save the token in a secure way and use it on every subsecuent call on my application? (which again, runs inside an iframe).

In short, I don't see any light at the end of the tunel and was wodering if anybody was able to work this out.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Restlet to communicate with NetSuite for that you'll need to enable Tokens based authentication in NetSuite. Also you'll need to create an app in NetSuite and generate OAuth tokens in NetSuite and save them in your app or server whichever you are going to use and then use these tokens to communicate with NetSuite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But maybe I was not clear enough on my question.
By doing this, I would have enabled Token Authentication for NetSuite. Basically, I would be able to make calls to Restlets by sending OAuth 1.0 in the header of the calls from an external app.
But my question goes beyond this. I wanted to know if there was a way for NetSuite to integrate with my external app OAuth 2.0 mechanism, by somehow providing a redirect URL in NetSuite that can handle the OAuth 2.0 mechanism of my application. For what I was able to research, I don't believe it's possible at the moment

Comment: @nachoargentina NetSuite doesn't provide OAuth mechanism, but if you are going to host your service in NetSuite itself you can try using **SingleSignOn**. Using SSO you don't need user to sign-in again in your app, user only needs to be logged-in in NetSuite and you can validate this using sso-id provided by NetSuite. You can check NetSuite Help for [SSO](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3526370.html)

Comment: got it, yes, seems like SingleSignOn is the way to go here.